# Store an image link in MySQL using Navicat Premium

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, navicat

I'm designing a dynamic website with Joomla and my PHP part is handled by Dreamweaver.

I'm using Navicat Premium to build my database.

One raw (varchar) in my database contains images. I found that having images as `BLOBS` in database is not a good idea.

But, Linking the image as `/img/image.php` in the cell is not working.

Actually I'm using Dreamweaver to fetch database table to the result page.

Please help me in-

1. Inserting the image link to the cell via Navicat Premium.
2. Any modifications I should do in Dreamweaver after inserting the proper link in the cell.

Thanks.!

Screenshot of result page

[image: Screenshot of result page]

Comment: And what is your problem? What do you mean, `But, Linking the image as /img/image.php in the cell is not working.` ?

Comment: Thanks, How to insert the image link to the cell in order to show the particular image in the front end? I just added /img/image.png in the cell. But the image is not showing. Only the typed word is showing (as above in the picture).

Comment: If you're using Joomla to build a dynamic website, why are you inserting data directly into the database? You should also normalize your DB because you're messing URL's with Addresses and Columns with Names

Comment: @nunorbastica - thanks. actually that's an example. I needed some more PHP works manually. That's why I use Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are mixing the Address and image. You have several option. Let's create an image field in your database, and when you loop through your records, check, is the image field is not empty, and if it's not, then show the image by: `<img src="PATH OF IMAGE COMES HERE" alt="" />` in your case `<img src="/images/image.png" alt="" />`

With your current design of your table, somehow you need to decide, is it an image, or is it an Address. Because if you just loop through your recordset, then there will be: `<img src="London" alt="" />`, and London is not a valid image resource.

Comment: Wow! This really worked. But, database didn't show the image when it was <img src="/images/image.png" alt="" />. Then, I deleted the "/" (without quotes" before the directory and its working now. Thanks alot.